# Help understanding Question - Abstract Algebra - Commutative Law and Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $R$ be a ring. Define a function $e : R[X]\times R \to R$ by the rule
$e\left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_k X^k,r\right) = \sum_{k=0}^n a_k r^n$.
In other words, given the input of a polynomial $f \in R[X]$ and an element $r\in R$,
$e(f,r)$ is obtained by substituting $r$ for $x$ in $f$.

Prove that, if $R$ is a commutative ring, then
$e(f,r) +e(g,r) = e(f +g,r)$ and
$e(f,r)· e(g,r) = e(f g,r)$
for any two linear polynomials $f$,$g \in R[x]$ and any $r ∈ R$.

So my understanding is that $f$ and $g$ are 2 random polynomials,
what I'm having difficult understanding is how would I show this satisfies the commutative law (as shown above), does $e$ mean its a whole other function?

What I've tried to do is to insert two polynomials, e.g. - $r+1$ and $r+2$ into the given function, but does this prove that $R$ is a commutative ring?
tip and help on understanding this question would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If $f$ and $g$ a linear polynomial, then $f(X)=aX+b$ and $g(X)=cX+d$, with $a,b,c,d\in R$. Besides,$$(fg)(X)=(aX+b)(cX+d).$$So\begin{align}e(fg,r)&=(ar+b)(cr+d)\\&=acr^2+(ad+bc)r+bd\text{ (since $R$ is commutative)}\\&=e(f,r)\cdot e(g,r).\end{align}Proving that $e(f+g,r)=e(f,r)+e(g,r)$ is even simpler.

Comment: so to prove commutative addition would i simply just sub in the two polynomialss? It seems a little too simple, there must be some extra steps required

Comment: The addition in a ring is *always* commutative. When we say that a ring is commutative, what this means is that the multiplication is commutative.